# Setting text font of Spinner items

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have the following code, to set the font type on a Spinner

```
private class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {
    private Context context;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<CharSequence> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        FontUtils.setRobotoFont(context, item);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**onCreate**

```
MySpinnerAdapter packageAdapter = (MySpinnerAdapter) ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.packageList,
                    R.layout.packageitem);
```

**R.layout.packageItem**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    style="@style/completedProminent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/tabSelected"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

As of now I am getting a ClassCastException @onCreate (source line above). What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try this `MySpinnerAdapter packageAdapter = (MySpinnerAdapter) ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.layout.packageitem,R.array.packageList);`. Constructor is taking `context, int, list` as parameter and you're passing `context, list, int`.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Now I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(21344):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(21344):  at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:361)
E/AndroidRuntime(21344):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:391)`

Comment: Does your listview has `android:entries` attribute?. Can you just point out the error line in code? And `packageList` is array of String or integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked was

```
private class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {
    private Context context;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, String[] objects, int textViewResourceId) {            
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View returnObject = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView item = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item);
        FontUtils.setRobotoFont(context, item);
        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

**onCreate**

```
MySpinnerAdapter packageAdapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(this,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.packageList),
            R.layout.packageitem);
```

Comment: Good to know that you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
MySpinnerAdapter packageAdapter = (MySpinnerAdapter)ArrayAdapter.createFromResource (this,R.layout.packageitem,R.array.packageList);‌​.
```

Constructor is taking `context, int, list` as parameter and you're passing `context, list, int.` That is why you're getting ClassCastException.